# wscat commands from script, how to pass

Tags: bash, websocket

I can connect to WS with wscat, I can send commands from console, but I have no idea how to pass commands from script.
I've tried few way, and always WAS is closed before commands are passed.

Generally I wnt something that will:
1. connect to WS
2. Send commands one by one, from list
3. Save input and output to file

Comment: Show us what you're trying, show us how it fails. We aren't mind readers -- we can't tell what the code you're trying to write is unless you show us.

Comment: BTW, `wscat` is pretty awful -- clearly designed for human interactive use rather than scripted invocation. Much to my disappointment, the same is also true of [`wsd`](https://github.com/alexanderGugel/wsd). It's a shame that such tools invoke `curl` -- something designed with ease-of-scripting in mind -- without sharing its design goals in that respect. [`websocat`](https://github.com/vi/websocat) appears to be written with a bit more consideration.

Comment: So I've try to run this in parallel

I've created 2 scripts
Test1.sh. with connecting to websocket: wscat -c wss://10.240.140.155
Test2.sh. With commands (starting with sleep 2)

I've tried to run this by running
./wscat.sh > test.txt

And in this wscat.sh I had:
sh ./Test1.sh & sh ./Test2.sh

So theoretically those script should run simultaneously, but I have alert from first script "connection was closed"

Comment: [Edit] that into the question, rather than leaving it in a comment.

Comment: That said, just because you're running those scripts at the same time doesn't mean you're connecting one's input to the other's output, or that they otherwise have anything to do with each other *other* than being running at the same time on the same computer.

Comment: And provide *actual text* of a minimal script that reproduces the problem (ideally using a publicly available websocket service, such as `ws://echo.websocket.org/`) -- see [mcve] definition.

Answer (score 8):

`wscat` is a poorly-chosen tool for the job; it isn't written to follow conventions that make it suitable for scripted use (such as keeping prompts on stderr rather than stdout; or suppressing prompts when output is not to a TTY; or treating an EOF as a signal to close a connection). Consider [`websocat`](https://github.com/vi/websocat) instead:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

runscript() {
  commands=( "first command" "second command" "third command" )

  for command in "${commands[@]}"; do
    echo "Writing command to server" >&2
    echo "$command"
    echo "Reading response from server (assuming exactly one line)" >&2
    read -r line
    echo "Received response: $line" >&2
  done

  # kill websocat, even if the websocket doesn't get closed
  kill "$PPID"
}

export -f runscript
websocat ws://echo.websocket.org sh-c:'exec bash -c runscript'
```

Comment: Thanks, how to install websocat?

Comment: It's written in rust; the build tool is `cargo`. Running `cargo build --release` in the source tree will create a release binary in `target/release/websocat`

Comment: There are also some pre-built versions of websocat at Github releases.

Comment: @Vi., ...by the way, the `sh-c:exec bash -c exported_function_name` idiom strikes me as clunky, but I'm not sure I see a better alternative (until the future pass-multiple-arguments-to-exec functionality is implemented, and it's tricky to see how to do that in a way that can be used as `spec1`, as opposed to making it only `spec2` allowed to contain multiple words, without restricting arguments' values). Do you have thoughts?

Comment: Passing arrays to `exec:` TODO list and should be in the next major version. `sh-c` is a quick hack to allow some cosy scripting without changing command line processing architecture.

Comment: Right; where I'm curious is the calling convention you plan to use for that TODO -- if you use a sigil to delimit between arguments passed in a single string, one restricts possible values to exclude that sigil. If one treats the first argument with a literal `:` (ie. itself starting with `exec:`) as a start of the next spec, likewise. Explicit specification of argvc would be unambiguous (`exec:2` `argv0` `argv1`), but that's obviously unfortunate for usability... or perhaps a prefix? `exec:-` `-argv0` `-argv1` is how `execline` does it (albeit w/ spaces), and that works well enough.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, The new websocat is released and `exec:` now has `--exec-args` option that makes all remaining options go into exec-ed program arguments.

Answer (score 5):

For simple things, you can use the `-x` parameter to give `wscat` some JSON to send after the connection is established, for example:

```
wscat --connect ws://example.com -w 1 -x '{"action": "helloWorld"}'
```

The `-w 1` will wait for one second after sending the message in case any replies come back.

Of course doing this connects to the WebSocket, sends the message, waits the given time for replies, then disconnects, so it's not a great choice if you need to keep the connection open between messages.

Comment: this does not work with php exec or system or shell_exec.

Comment: @user2573099: It should if you set up your exec call properly.  Try it with another command like `echo hello` first and if you can get that working but wscat still doesn't, post a new question and we'll help out.  Note that PHP has actual Websocket support which is going to be a lot more robust than calling `wscat` which is only intended for debugging.